# How can I access list of all products in Root Category in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, category

I've tried **/catalog/category/view/id/2** and by url key all **.html**
it works for child categories, but for Base Categories got 404

is there any  way to do it without coding?

Comment: Hi there, no it is not possible without altering the code to show all the products for that category, this is the answer to you from my side and my best guess. Thanks.